# MTP file transfer freezes/locks screen

Tags: 14.04, gnome, android, mtp

As per subject, when I try to transfer files to my Android devices (Samsung tablet, HTC phone, ...) via MTP, the screen freezes/locks.
I have to resort using the network and the speeds there are *just* ~1MB/s. Not ideal when you want to transfer GBs of files...

What can I do?